# Meteor variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor server code is complaining

> Exception in callback of async function: ReferenceError: myConn is not defined

The variable `myConn` is defined in ddp.js and is used in method.js,
Any idea why and how to fix it? thx

```
//server/ddp.js
let myConn = DDP.connect('http://localhost:5000');


//server/method.js
myConn.call('myMethod', {obj}, () => {})
```

Comment: `myConn` is local to `ddp.js`. You can either export it from the file where it is defined and import it into `method.js` or make it a global by removing the `let`

Comment: @MichelFloyd you should probably turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let` limits the variable's scope to the block or statement in which it is used.

`var` defines a variable locally to an entire function or procedure.

To define a variable globally and accesible between multiple files  avoid using `let` or `var` and just assign a default value to its name.  Example:

`myVarName="";`

Comment: Aka "pollution of global scope", not necessarily a bad thing (this was the way in Meteor before it managed imports), but you should be careful with it.